# Should my roof be level and/or even?

Tags: roof, uneven

New roof fitted. It not level and even. Roofer says it not there job to level out roof? So unsure if that true or not. I have been told I should of had a joiner level roof before roof was fitted?
So I need to know is this normal for roofing company's not level roof or tell me at the time roof was not level so I had option of getting a joiner in to level roof.

Comment: It depends.  If the existing deck is warped (maybe from water or simple weight), but still in good enough shape that it doesn't need to be replaced, then it's not the roofer's responsibility to remediate.  If it's damaged, then the roofer should repair it, in part or in whole.  Typically their quote will include replacing a handful of 4x8 sheets; if your roof has more damage the quote will list additional sheets at $X per.

Comment: What kind of roof and what kind of problems exactly are you seeing?  Obviously the roof needs to shed water so you don't mean that it should literally be "level" but what do you mean?

Comment: "Flat." The word is "flat." Aligned with the horizon is "level." Usually such pedantry annoys me, but I was genuinely confused for longer than I care to admit.

Comment: "Level" might indeed be the right word, if we're talking about a visible edge rather than about the plane. However, I operate by the principle that, in a 100-year-old house, *nothing* is plumb, level, flat, square, or otherwise true to its ideal form. And that's probably a realistic attitude for most houses.

Answer (score 6):

It depends in the type of roof and how much the ridge is out of level and the roof out of square. But the roofer is technically correct. Where I live, it's even illegal for a roofer to change the wood below the roof without a separate license. However, it would have been the professional thing to do, from the roofer's standpoint, to tell you that the roof could use some repairs before starting the job.

Not to defend your roofer, because I don't know them, but sometimes the problem with telling people that they need $10,000 in repairs before the $10,000 roofing job can be done is that they then accuse you of adding unnecessary stuff to the bill.  The client then goes and pays $15,000 to the more "honest" roofer who said no repairs were necessary. Even though the first roofer had offered a lower no-repairs price.

And sometimes it is really a matter of opinions and taste if repairs are necessary. On a very old house, or a house that otherwise needs serious repairs (eg siding falling apart), it might not be worth repairing the roof structure, because an off-level roof, while not ideal, fits the rest of the house, and saves the owner $10,000, which the owner can then use towards more urgent repairs. On some types of roofs and newer houses, it's better to save up the money and fix it right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the work conforms to local building regulations, you have no recourse unless you at least verbally agreed to a broader scope of work. You really need to know your full scope of work when soliciting bids so you can compare "apples to apples" to make your final decision. One guy may intend to do the scope you want, while the lower price guy is "cutting corners." An ethical contractor will tell you about the corners he intends to cut. On second thought, maybe that's just simple wisdom to possibly get paid for the broader scope and/or avoid acrimonious situations with angry customers.

The situation is awkward for somebody soliciting bids who doesn't know the full scope until speaking with their third candidate contractor. Now what do you do with the first two inadequate bids? (You get yet another bid from the third guy for the same scope and then get a price for the work beyond that original scope.) Personally when I'm not expert enough to know my full scope, I feel somewhat unethical taking information for free from one contractor and calling back the earlier contractors. In this situation I prefer contractors who charge a reasonable fee for their bids. These contractors aren't just bidding my job, they're also providing their expertise to dumb ol' me.